# Speed up CSS3 translating effect

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div translating forward and backwards infinitely. So, I want to change div's "speed" randomly. For increasing and decreasing speed I'm trying to change animation-duration property, but after this:

```
$("#rectangle").css('-webkit-animation-duration', randomValue + 's');
```

nothing happens. 
Div has to behave, like it's just increasing/decreasing speed

EDIT: So, maybe anyone can give an advice how it could be made, if my way doesn't work properly?

Comment: ... and for forward and backwards you have it done? ...

Comment: Do you use a webkit browser? ;-)

Comment: Yes, the movement is working fine and i use chrome, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I plotted the general idea I was thinking of in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RrSV8/1/)..

I think you missed something related to the prefixes and the browsers.. as you can see the example I've written is working, kind of buggy too.

As you can see all I had to do is to invoke same code but with prefixes for firefox and webkit:

```
$("div").css("-webkit-animation-duration", lastTime + "ms").css("animation-duration", lastTime + "ms");
```

You will have to be careful with the animation duration.. because you changing the duration in a time the animation is still running will reposition the element depending on where it should be at that keyframe for that period..

Example.. if the animation is 2 seconds.. and it is 90% done.. changing the duration to 4 seconds will make it 90% of the 50% (2 / 4 seconds) done.. and that's the reason for the buggy animation you have seen in the fiddle.

I hope this helps..

Comment: You do know that you can pass object literals to the `css()` function? +1 for pointing out the issues and the fiddle though. ;-)